# Fabric "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: python, fabric

I have the following fabric task:

```
@task
def deploy_west_ec2_ami(name, puppetClass, size='m1.small', region='us-west-1', basedn='joe', ldap='arch-ldap-01', secret='secret', subnet='subnet-d43b8abd', sgroup='sg-926578fe'):
    execute(deploy_ec2_ami, name='%s',puppetClass='%s',size='%s',region='%s',basedn='%s',ldap='%s',secret='%s',subnet='%s',sgroup='%s' %(name, puppetClass, size, region, basedn, ldap, secret, subnet, sgroup))
```

However when I run the command:

```
fab deploy_west_ec2_ami:test,java
```

I get the following Traceback:

```
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/fabric/main.py", line 710, in main
                *args, **kwargs
              File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 321, in execute
                results['<local-only>'] = task.run(*args, **new_kwargs)
              File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 113, in run
                return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
              File "/home/bcarpio/Projects/githubenterprise/awsdeploy/fabfile.py", line 35, in deploy_west_ec2_ami
                execute(deploy_ec2_ami, name='%s',puppetClass='%s',size='%s',region='%s',basedn='%s',ldap='%s',secret='%s',subnet='%s',sgroup='%s' %(name, puppetClass, size, region, basedn, ldap, secret, subnet, sgroup))
            TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I am not sure I understand why. I am pretty sure I have all the values defined here just fine.

Also when I run the execute task deploy_ec2_ami as so:

```
deploy_ec2_ami:test,java,m1.small,us-west-1,'dc\=test\,dc\=net',ldap-01,secret,subnet-d43b8abd,sg-926578fe
```

It works just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the issue was when using execute you must define a host=. My other fab task doesn't need host= so I just put in regular python:

```
deploy_ec2_ami (name, puppetClass, size, region, basedn, ldap, secret, subnet, sgroup)
```

And it all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a set of keyword arguments to the `execute` method, and only the last value is considered the target for the string interpolation:

```
sgroup='%s' %(name, puppetClass
        , size, region, basedn, ldap, secret, subnet, sgroup))
```

There is no need to use string interpolation here; just pass all the arguments on to the `execute` method:

```
execute(deploy_ec2_ami, name=name, puppetClass=puppetClass, size=size, region=region, basedn=basedn, ldap=ldap, secret=secret, subnet=subnet, sgroup=sgroup)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the line

```
sgroup='%s' %(name, puppetClass, size, region, basedn, ldap, secret, subnet, sgroup)
```

String interpolation works for one string, not for all arguments. I mean

```
'%s %s' % (arg1, arg2)
```

but if you try

```
'%s' % (arg1, arg2)
```

there is no room for arg2

If you want to keep doing string interpolation I suggest doing this:

```
execute(deploy_ec2_ami, name='%s' % name, puppetClass='%s' % puppetClass, size='%s' % size, region='%s' % region, and so on
```

As you are not changing anything in the parameters, I would  definitely go for Brian solution